# How can i change chrome history with sqlite3 python?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

This is my code

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect("path to chrome history")
c = conn.cursor()
c.executemany("UPDATE urls SET url = REPLACE(url,.foo.,.foo-bar.) WHERE url LIKE %foo%;")
conn.close()
```

It throws the following error:

```
c.executemany("UPDATE urls SET url = REPLACE(url,.foo.,.foo-bar.) WHERE url LIKE %foo%;")
TypeError: executemany expected 2 arguments, got 1
```

How can I change the history in Google Chrome using sqlite3 in Python?

Comment: You are only executing one sql command, so use `execute` instead of `executemany`.

Comment: c.execute("UPDATE urls SET url = REPLACE(url,.foo.,.foo-bar.) WHERE url LIKE %foo%;")
sqlite3.OperationalError: near ".": syntax error

Comment: Now you have a sql error. The strings in `REPLACE` need to be in single quotes. (I don't do a lot of SQL stuff, so I can't help much more.)

Comment: c.execute("UPDATE urls SET url = REPLACE(url,foo,foo-bar) WHERE url LIKE foo")
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: foo

Comment: I don't think you are using `REPLACE` correctly. https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/sqlite/sqlite-replace-statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some time to look at this after lunch and this is what I hobbled together. **Use at your own risk** (make a backup of the "History" file before running this).

```
import sqlite3
 
conn = sqlite3.connect(r"path to chrome history")

c = conn.cursor()

for url in c.execute("SELECT * FROM urls WHERE url LIKE '%foo%'"):
    # Execute returns a tuple. Need to convert to list to edit.
    # Then convert back to tuple for use in f-string
    url = list(url)
    url[1] = url[1].replace("foo", "foo-bar") # String replace
    url = tuple(url)
    c.execute(f"REPLACE INTO urls VALUES {url}")

c.close()
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Note: Chrome has to be closed for this to run else the file will be locked.